# K8s client nullptr dereference

Tags: go, kubernetes, nullptr

Following the k8s/controller-runtime/client example code (see [here](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.4/pkg/client#example-Client-Create)), which goes a bit like this

```golang
var c client.Client

func main() {
    // Using a typed object.
    pod := &corev1.Pod{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Namespace: "namespace",
            Name:      "name",
        },
        Spec: corev1.PodSpec{
            Containers: []corev1.Container{
                {
                    Image: "nginx",
                    Name:  "nginx",
                },
            },
        },
    }
    // c is a created client.
    _ = c.Create(context.Background(), pod) // nil deref here  
}
```

I get a nullptr dereference on `_ = c.Create(context.Background(), pod)`. To me this makes sense, since I declared `c`, but never initialised it. However the example code also does that. What is going on here?

Comment: *"What is going on here?"* -- It's an __example__ of how use the code, not a valid production-ready program. Given that `client.Client` is an interface type, `var c client.Client` by itself will **always** result in a variable `c` that is `nil` (the zero value of interface types). The comment above the `c.Create` call clearly states that that statement depends on a properly created client, not a `nil` "example client".

Comment: I should add though, that it seems to me to be bad practice to include [executable examples](https://go.dev/blog/examples) in godoc that compile but fail at runtime. So, while one should never *rely* on the examples to be complete, *expecting* them to compile and execute is fair, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to initialise the client can be found here: https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.4/pkg/client#example-New

```golang
cl, err := client.New(config.GetConfigOrDie(), client.Options{})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("failed to create client")
    os.Exit(1)
}
```